# Get href attribute on jQuery

Tags: jquery, get, href, each, attr

I have some table rows

```
<tr class="b_row">
    <td>
        <div class="cpt">
            <h2>
                <a href="/ref/ref/1.html">example</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<!--more elements -->

<tr class="b_row">
    <td>
        <div class="cpt">
            <h2>
                <a href="/ref/two/23.html">example N</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to get hyperlinks in  attribute. I use this script

```
function openAll()
{
    $("tr.b_row").each(function(){
    var a_href = $('div.cpt').find('h2 a').attr('href');
    alert ("Href is: " + a_href);
}
```

Problem: variable `a_href` is always / ref/ref/1.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

In loop you should refer to the current procceded element, so write:

```
var a_href = $(this).find('div.cpt h2 a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 10):

```
var a_href = $('div.cpt').find('h2 a').attr('href');
```

should be

```
var a_href = $(this).find('div.cpt').find('h2 a').attr('href');
```

In the first line, your query searches the entire document.  In the second, the query starts from your `tr` element and only gets the element underneath it.  (You can combine the `find`s if you like, I left them separate to illustrate the point.)

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
$(function(){
    $("tr.b_row").each(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).find('div.cpt h2 a').attr('href');
    alert ("Href is: "+a_href);

    });
});
```

**See a working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/4Ea4k/1/

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, use `this` as the context: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context

```
var a_href = $('div.cpt', this).find('h2 a').attr('href');
```

Which says, find `'div.cpt'` only inside `this`

Answer (score 1):

add a reference to `this`, which refers to your `b_row`:

```
$("tr.b_row").each(function(){
    var a_href = $( this ).find('div.cpt h2 a').attr('href');
    alert ("Href is: "+a_href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` for get the desire element.

```
function openAll()
{
     $("tr.b_row").each(function(){
        var a_href = $(this).find('.cpt h2 a').attr('href');
        alert ("Href is: "+a_href);
     });
}
```